# Recursively remove the adjacent duplicate characters and return the resultant string

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a string, complete the given function to recursively remove the adjacent duplicate characters and return the resultant string. If there are no characters left in the resultant string, return "-1" (without quotes).

```
Sample Test Cases
Sample Input: ABCCBCBA
Output: ACBA

Explanation: (ABCCBCBA --> ABBCBA --> ACBA)
Sample Input: AA
Sample Output: -1
Explanation: Return -1, since there are no characters in the final string
```

My solution failing in   -1 case

```
public String removeAdj( String src)
{
    if(src == null)
         return null;

    if(src.length() ==1)
        return src;



     String result;

     if(src.CharAt(0) == src.charAt(1) )
          return removeAdj(src.SubString(1) );
     else
          result = src.CharAt(0) + removeAdj(src.SubString(1) );

     return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code in case AA input its giving A

Comment: What test cases are you using?  Also have you stepped through it and found any problem areas?

Comment: ABCCBCBA--O/p->ABCBCBA Go to this http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php this site and just paste your code

Comment: yes its giving A I want to get -1

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a recursive solution for this.

```
public String removeAdj(String src) {
   int i = 0;
   while (i < src.length() - 1) {
       int j = i;
       while (j < src.length() - 1 && src.charAt(i) == src.charAt(j + 1)) {
           j++;
       }
       if (j > i) {
           src = src.substring(0, i) + src.substring(j + 1, src.length());
           i--;
       } else {
           i++;
       }
   }
   if (i < 1) {
       return "-1";
   } else {
       return src;
   }
}
```

Note that this solution removes substrings of more than two duplicated characters, AAA for example, but if you don't require that it can be easily simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem. If String is 1 character in length, return -1, not the src.

Is it your solution?

Comment: Don't discuss the question with an answer, unless you have some solution to offer. Questions and alike should be asked as a comment to the original question instead! You suggestion is not a good one, because the function return type is `string`.

Comment: omg, then return "-1". This IS actually a solution to this "problem"